# Parsing Large Xml

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

How can i parse this XML with C# WP7 to different lists for binding different panorama pages:

```
<root>
 <main1>
  <item>
   <id>1</id>
  </item>
 <item>
  <id>2</id>
 </item>
 </main1>
 <main2>
  <item>
   <id>1</id>
  </item>
  <item>
   <id>2</id>
  </item>
 <main2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient (and memory preserving) way to parse large XML documents is to use the [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx). Se the [MSDN howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056.aspx) for a reasonable example.

The easiest way to parse an XML document is usually the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class, but that class reads the whole document into memory at once and is not recommendable for large documents.

Comment: I don't think XmlReader is available on the phone, I think one has to use Linq to Xml.